# How to add an image and text on the right side of navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

[image: modelNavigationBar]

I tried to make the navigation-bar like this but nothing is going on right. I have added rightbarbutton successfully but in the left side I couldn't add the navigation bar.
I have tried these following codes

```
private func configureItems(){
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: nil)
    //self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: nil)
    //self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "image8"), style: .done, target: self, action: nil)
    let customView = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40))
    customView.text = "John Doe"
    customView.textAlignment = .left
    customView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
        customView: customView
    )
//        let customImageView = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: "image"))
//        customImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35)
//        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
//            customView: customView)
    let navController = navigationController!

        let image = UIImage(named: "image8")!
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

        let bannerWidth = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.width
        let bannerHeight = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.center = navController.navigationBar.center
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)

        navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Comment: can someone help me out

Comment: I take it this isn't for SwiftUI?

Comment: @cole suggest me edit pls

Comment: @Developeder can you help me